# Generation payments and schedule automatically using Stripe Billing API

Tags: stripe-payments

I need to use the **Stripe Billing API** such that my payments amount and schedule is dynamically generated. For instance the user should be able to do the following:

> I want to pay £5, £10, £11, £13 on dates a, b, c, d

I would like all of these items to appear on one invoice. I have read through the Stripe API docs but not making much sense to me. For instance I have tested using the following (creating a single schedule). By the premise I would need to create 4 separate schedules which doesn't seem to be the right way of doing something like this.

```
schedule = stripe.SubscriptionSchedule.create(
  customer='cus_xxx',
  start_date='now',
  end_behavior="release",
  phases=[{
    'plans': [{
      'price_data': {
        'unit_amount': 1000,
        'currency': 'USD',
        'product': 'prod_HMDoA6Jpf0U1Fh',
        'recurring': {
        'interval': 'day',
        'interval_count': 11,
      },
    },
    }],
    'iterations': 1,
  }],
)
```

Comment: When you say that all of these items should appear on one Invoice, that would conflict with paying on four different dates. An Invoice in Stripe is a single payment, which can be for multiple line items, but it can't be split up into multiple payments on different dates. If you want to make four payments, you need to use four invoices (which Subscription Schedules would support as you've mentioned). Is that the correct understanding of what you're looking to do?

Comment: Quite right and it seems to work aswell (ran a quick test using CURL) using the Billing API. I just misunderstood how the Billings API was working